# R replacing NA's by referencing parent item's value

Tags: r, if-statement, na

I am trying to replicate an excel expression that I have for filling in missing Topic information using an Index and Match on two values.

The columns that are relevant are Topic (factor), Post.ID (int) and Parent.ID (int).

```
str(df)
'data.frame':   1995 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Topic    : Factor w/ 76 levels "Winter Olympics",..: 8 8 8 8 8 6 6
 $ Post.id  : int  295221 290611 288426 290823 292140 289990 289989
 $ Parent.id: int  NA NA NA NA 290611 ...
```

Each row will have a post id, but the parent.id is populated if the post is a child of another post and is the same id as the parent's post id. The hierarchy is only ever one level.  I am trying to add a topic to the child by matching the Post.ID against the Parent.ID and taking the parent's Topic.

Here is the excel formula:

```
=IF([Topic]=0,IFERROR(IF([Parent ID]=0,[Topic],(INDEX([Topic]$[StartCell]:[Topic]$[EndCell], MATCH([Parent ID],[Post ID]$[StartCell]:[Post ID]$[EndCell],0))))),[Topic]),[Topic])
```

I've tried the following ifelse function and it works, except it converts the factors to ints.

```
ifelse(is.na(df$Topic), 
         df$Topic[df$Post.id %in% df$Parent.id], 
         df$Topic)
```

I tried converting the exact thing to if_else, but i get the following error

```
Evaluation error: `true` must be length 1995 (length of `condition`) or one, not 429.
```

I also tried creating a separate dataframe of the distinct Topics and Post ID, renaming the post ID and then doing a left_join, but that is really clunky and I know there must be a cleaner way to do it.

Comment: Could you provide data?

Comment: Seems like you have `Post.id`s with both a missing `Topic` and a missing `Parent.id`.

Comment: That is true. That could just be a post without a topic. it isn't a required field. In that case, I would return an NA for the Topic. Also, depending on the what timeframe I use in the query, I may not have the parent issue to match against. In which case, I'd also NA.

Comment: I _think_ it should work if you change the second argument to `df$Topic[match(df$Parent.id, df$Post.id)]`..? It's hard to be sure without some test data.

Comment: With `df$Post.id %in% df$Parent.id` you are just checking if the post on that row ever occurs as a parent, and indexing topic based on that boolean, i.e. dropping topics where the post is never a parent. It doesn't seem like that would produce the result that you're after. Rather you want to find the topic from the row where the current post's parent occurs as post, right?

Comment: That's right. i'm trying to find the Topic from the row where the current's post occurs. I tried using the match code you posted and I get an error : 'Error: condition must be a logical, not list'

Comment: That's an error for the first argument to `if_else`. Just to clarify, what I meant was: `if_else(is.na(topic), topic[match(parent, post)], topic)` with the relevant name changes.

Comment: That worked perfectly! I had messed up how I put it together. Thanks so much!